# Display Current Loggedin user Rank

Tags: php

I have written the code to display ranks to all the users.
But, i'm unable to display current logged in user rank.
Here is the code i have written.

```
<?php
        $var = mysql_query("SELECT quiz_grades.grade, user.username FROM quiz_grades JOIN user ON quiz_grades.userid=user.id WHERE `quiz`=$quid ORDER BY quiz_grades.grade DESC");
        $i=0;
        while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($var))
        {
            $i++;
            echo $result1['username'];
            echo $result1['grade'];
            echo $i;
        }
?>
```

Please help me to display current logged in user rank only.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you need to firstly get your current user's ID / username then get the rank of him.

Comment: I think you must have the id of logged in user in Session . Just put the condition where the user.id is equal to logged in user id so it will give the record of that user only.

Comment: `mysql_query` is depreciated.

Comment: Hi, Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit" Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question? If yes, please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly Where is your current logged in user's ID/username? isn't there any session ? `$_SESSION['id']`  or `$_SESSION['username'];`  so if you don't have  When the user logs in set the session of user first

Notice : `mysql_query is deprecated`

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $current_logged_in_user_id; // $current_logged_in_user_id is just an example variable to give you an idea of making the session according to id which you fetch when user logs in.
```

i will show you manual user id based query

```
 $userid = '3';
```

as later described by the question poster , the user id is :

```
$USER->id
```

and then inside your query user the above variable to get current user's rank / whole data `remove quizid` condition.

```
<?php
$var = mysql_query("SELECT quiz_grades.grade, user.username 
                FROM quiz_grades 
                JOIN user ON quiz_grades.userid=user.id 
                WHERE quiz_grades.quiz = $quizid AND quiz_grades.userid = $USER->id ORDER BY quiz_grades.grade DESC");
        $i=0;
        while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($var))
        {
            $i++;
            echo $result1['username'];
            echo $result1['grade'];
            echo $i;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: USER->id is current logged in user id

Comment: <?php
$var = mysql_query("SELECT quiz_grades.grade, user.username 
                FROM quiz_grades 
                JOIN user ON quiz_grades.userid=user.id 
                WHERE `quiz`=$quid AND userid = $USER->id ORDER BY quiz_grades.grade DESC");
        $i=0;
        while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($var))
        {
            $i++;
            echo $result1['username'];
            echo $result1['grade'];
            echo $i;
        }
    ?>

Comment: see my edit and try with that , i have removed quizid.

Comment: check the edit and get back to me , so i will recheck the whole situation again.

Comment: your edit showing all the attempts with ranks with current user

Comment: so you want the result to be quiz based right?. see my edit again and try that

Comment: SELECT quiz_grades.grade, user.username FROM quiz_grades JOIN user ON quiz_grades.userid=user.id WHERE quiz=$quid AND userid=$USER->id ORDER BY quiz_grades.grade DESC

Comment: this is my original code for selected quiz and current user

Comment: you can't use quiz   and userid  directly inside where clause. you have to give them there parent table name as well.

Comment: If you want to check i will provide the url and login details

Comment: sure privde me with that , email me :  arshsinghmultani@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit" Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question? If yes, please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

**USE username='Current_user_id'** to show who is logged in currently..

**specify the username condition** also in the query

```
<?php $var = mysql_query("SELECT quiz_grades.grade, user.username 
                FROM quiz_grades 
                JOIN user ON quiz_grades.userid=user.id 
                WHERE `quiz`=$quid and `username`='$userid' ORDER BY quiz_grades.grade DESC");
        $i=0;
        while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($var))
        {
            $i++;
            echo $result1['username'];
            echo $result1['grade'];
            echo $i;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I already tried with that, but, forgot to post.
This is my entire code. $USER->id is current logged in user variable.


`<?php $var = mysql_query("SELECT quiz_grades.grade, user.username 
                FROM quiz_grades 
                JOIN user ON quiz_grades.userid=user.id 
                WHERE `quiz`=$quid and `userid`='$USER->id' ORDER BY quiz_grades.grade DESC");
        $i=0;
        while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($var))
        {
            $i++;
            echo $result1['username'];
            echo $result1['grade'];
            echo $i;
        }
    ?>`

Comment: @user2702500 update your question with the full code instead of squeezing it into a comment :)

Comment: use **userid='$userid ' **

Comment: Hi, Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit" Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question? If yes, please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?